# Suggestion on replacing an is_regex call in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Can someone help me with replacing this guard case in Elixir ?

```
def contains(collection,element) do
r = case collection do
      c when is_tuple(c)           -> element in tuple_to_list(c)
      c when is_list(c)            -> element in c
      c when is_regex(element)     -> Regex.match?(element, c)
      c when is_bitstring(element) -> String.contains?(c, element)
    end

if (not r), do: Message.fail(collection, element, __ENV__.function)
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Regex.regex?(element)` in it's place.

Comment: but then `Regex.regex?` can't be use as guard conditions right ? That is my hang up.

Comment: Correct, Erlang (and therefore Elixir) only allows a limited set of calls in guards: http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/5.html

Comment: In upcoming Elixir versions you will be able to match on `%Regex{}`. But right now since we are in between records and structs, we need to rely on such functions.